# Excel "super duper" vlookup formula needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

If I have the following data:

```
123, thomas
123, gordon
123, smith
334, joey
334, nancy
3452, angela
3452, liza
```

I want a formula to produce the following results:

```
123, thomas, gordon, smith
334, joey, nancy
3452, angela, liza
```

Is there an easy and/or efficient way to do this with a formula? If not, how can I do this with VBA?

Answer (score 3):

No doubt there is a slick VBA solution, and some really smart person who visits this site will come through with one for you.  However.... I came up with a solution that can get you the results you need if you are willing to use a helper column and then a final filter.

I set up your data beginning in the 2nd row.  Note that I split your data at the comma delimiter into 2 columns. I added a "helper" column, a "string" column to do the desired concatenation, and a "FinalFilter" column as shown.  [image]

Here is what the formulas look like (you might need to change your browser Zoom to see it):

[image]

And finally, just filter on the "FinalFilter" column = 1, and you have your desired results:

[image]